# Snowflake/SQL Accounting for Null Values in Count/Group Output

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

No real idea here how to go about this but I am taking two tables that I have joined on a common user ID and I need to calculate the average count of "tickets" per User ID for all users taking into account users with null tickets submitted.

```
SELECT u.UID, u.DATE_CREATED, COUNT(distinct t.tickets) AS COUNT
FROM users u, tickets t

WHERE u.USER_ID = t.USER_ID
GROUP BY UID, DATE_CREATED
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

***Note** table user has user id info and is joined with tickets table that has ticket ID*

There are initially 200 records of user IDs but after running this query, it returns 170 users and the count of tickets submitted like shown below. I believe that the missing 30 users have a null value when counting the tickets.

[QUESTION] Is it possible to group the null values as '0' and output the associated User ID and 0 value as COUNT to the below example output?

Current Output:

```
UID   COUNT
252    1291
251    1222
250    1000
[..]   [...]
212     1
128     1
121     1
```

Desired Output (Counting UID's where Count is Null)
Current Output:

```
UID   COUNT
252    1291
251    1222
250    1000
[..]   [...]
212     1
128     1
121     1
52      0
23      0 
11      0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Even just know what tables columns come from helps.

Comment: Sure! One Moment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.UID, COUNT(distinct tickets)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON u.USER_ID = t.USER_ID
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Comment: Users without a ticket will not show up with this query

Comment: omg that is so true, I had read it as they wanted the count on ticket with no users assigned. I have now flipped it around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all *users* then use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT U.UID, U.DATE_CREATED, COUNT(distinct T.tickets) AS COUNT
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     tickets t
     ON u.USER_ID = t.USER_ID
GROUP BY U.UID, U.DATE_CREATED
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```